# azcopy in cloud shell fails attempting to copy source storage account contents to target storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

error is 'failed to perform copy command due to error: no SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public'

command is formed per the MS doc page.

azcopy copy "http://source.blob.core.windows.net?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-02-15T02:43:29Z&st=2020-02-14T18:43:29Z&spr=https&sig=Jojd%2FWIfjCza7yNtkt%2FeaFOepyxaunBnjH6O3xCKOto%3D" "http://target.blob.core.windows.net" --recursive

SAS token was generated within minutes of attempted execution, public access on source storage account is set to container, not private.  Command syntax is identical to that in the MS documentation.

I'm thinking that I have overlooked something basic, probably staring me in the face, anyone see anything obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following this [section](http://Copy%20all%20containers,%20directories,%20and%20blobs%20to%20another%20storage%20account), then please specify `sas token` for the `target storage url`.

Here is the test with the latest version of [azcopy v10.3.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#download-azcopy).

The command:

```
azcopy copy "https://yy7.blob.core.windows.net/?sasToken" "https://yy88.blob.core.windows.net/?sasToken" --recursive
```

The test result:

[image]